# Collapse menu with hover/fadeTo

Tags: jquery, menu, hover

This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/MRMr4/2/

Of course there is a problem.

As you can see, when I move the mouse to the **section** that was displayed just below, the section disappears. How can I change my jQuery so this section only disappears when the mouse out of the *#menu* or *#products*?

```
$('#menu').hover(function(){
    $('#products').fadeTo('fast', 1);
}, function(){
    $('#products').fadeTo('fast', 0);
});

$('#products').mouseover(function(){
    $('#products').show();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#products').fadeTo('fast', 0);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right this approach uses a timeout to delay the collapsing of your product window. This will allow you to move your mouse from you menu to your product window without it collapsing on you...!

```
$('#menu').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#products').fadeIn(100);

    var timeout = null;

    // Set timeout to delay collapse of product window
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(collapse, 300);
    });

    // Cancel the collapse event if product window is entered
    $('#products').mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        collapse();
    });
});

function collapse() {
    $('#products').fadeOut(100);
}
```

Have a look at [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRMr4/24/).

Comment: Ok, now I need to make this happen also when mouse out from the #menu, not just #products.